# How can I install a package on Ubuntu if I have no internet access?

Tags: 12.04, fortran

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I have no access to the internet on my computer and am trying to install all my required software through another computer. I have downloaded the `deb` file for `gfortran` version 4.5, and now I am looking for options to install the same on the computer which has Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Assuming that you aren't referring to the Saskatoon Business College, what exactly do you mean by "SBC"?

Comment: Single Board Computer(Intel Atom), same as any intel PC with ubuntu 12.04 OS on it, my main interest is how one can install compilers,etc., with out using ubuntu software center or with no internet access.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried [`apt-offline`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Use_apt-offline)?

Comment: @SirCharlo I just went through apt-offline steps, wondering what to replace with the package that(gfortran) I want to install.

Comment: no you people have not addressed my query and closed it stating duplicate.... why should one stick to the internet for installing packages.. can't we just download the package and find steps to install it. I have ptp-master-6.0.0-201206130212.zip which is a photorn package and I am looking for the steps to install it, guys any body else can help me with this.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the two pc's have same architecture?! and same version of Ubuntu? Also if they have same update then you can cheat and copy the deb packages from `/var/cache/apt/archives` to your second pc and then `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`  I work this method sometimes myself

Here is a [link](http://channikhabra.blogspot.com/2011/07/why-not-to-install-linux-offline-and.html) about some methods how to install a softwar with no-internet connection

Also you can use [keryx](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/keryx-offline-package-installation-made-easy-in-ubuntu/) to download deb files from windows

Also you can use [apt-offline](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT)

Comment: The PC which has internet access runs on WindowsXP

Comment: you have to resolve all dependencies and downlaod them and copy to other desktop and then `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. Browse four your package 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/
http://packages.debian.org/
http://www.getdeb.net/